# How to generate high dimensional random orthogonal complex vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces, orthogonality, dimension-theory-analysis

I'm generating a few random vectors in 1000D space and they seem to be indeed almost orthongonal as evident by dot product. However, when I make them complex-valued, I lose that orthogonality, why is that? and how to make them orthogonal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ be $N$-dimensional complex vectors:
$$\mathbf{a} = \left [ \begin{matrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \\ \vdots \\ a_N \end{matrix} \right ], \quad \mathbf{b} = \left [ \begin{matrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \\ \vdots \\ b_N \end{matrix} \right ]$$
where $$a_k = c_k + i C_k, \quad a_k \in \mathbb{C}, ~ c_k \in \mathbb{R}, ~ C_k \in \mathbb{R}$$
and $$b_k = d_k + i D_k, \quad b_k \in \mathbb{C}, ~ d_k \in \mathbb{R}, ~ D_k \in \mathbb{R}$$
As explained by the Wikipedia [Dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Complex_vectors) article, for dot product to make any sense, it has to be redefined for complex vectors as
$$\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} = \sum_k a_k \overline{b_k}$$
where $$\overline{b_k} = d_k - i D_k$$
so that
$$\left\lVert \mathbf{a} \right\rVert^2 = \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{a} = \sum_k c_k^2 + C_k^2$$
which also means that
$$\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} = -\mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{a}$$
and leads to
$$\cos \theta = \frac{\operatorname{Re}\left( \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} \right)}{\left\lVert\mathbf{a} \right\rVert \left\lVert\mathbf{b}\right\rVert}$$

In other words, 
$$\mathbf{a} \perp \mathbf{b} \iff \sum_k c_k d_k + C_k D_k = \sum_k C_k d_k - c_k D_k$$

With this definition of dot product, random complex vectors are indeed almost orthogonal.

To orthogonalise a vector with respect to another, you can use the first step of [Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process):
$$\mathbf{b}^\prime = \mathbf{b} - \mathbf{a} \frac{ \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} }{\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{a}}$$
which ensures that $\mathbf{b}^\prime \perp \mathbf{a}$.